# Did Leibniz ever express any opinion about Aristotle, Plato or Archimedes?

Tags: biographical-details, leibniz

Since Leibniz is known to have expressed opinions about Descartes' and Newton's abilities maybe he did the same for the prominent thinkers of antiquity.
Did Leibniz ever express any opinion about Aristotle, Plato or Archimedes?

Comment: The SEP article on [Leibniz](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/) describes the role of Plato and Aristotle in Leibniz's life, education, and work.

Comment: See [Leibniz on Other Philosophers](http://philosophyfaculty.ucsd.edu/faculty/rutherford/Leibniz/otherphilosophers.php), although it is not very clear what sorts of opinions about "abilities" you are looking for. Like the thinly veiled personal barbs Leibniz and Newton traded in the priority dispute?

Comment: Leibniz works are full of references to Aristotle; many also regarding Plato. Check with some edition of Leibniz's selected works (and letters).

Comment: @Conifold  Not only that, anything that he expressed about them or their work that heavily implies something about them will do.

Comment: For A and P, see e.g. Gottfried Wilhelm Leibnizm [Discourse on Metaphysics](https://books.google.it/books?id=oWwBauYO8XAC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Regarding Archimedes, see e.g. Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz, [The Early Mathematical Manuscripts](https://books.google.it/books?id=tCmp_c3Q9S8C&printsec=frontcover)